# How do you determine which SKSpriteNode was clicked?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, osx-mavericks, skspritenode

I'm trying to use an SKSpriteNode as a transition from one scene to the next. How can I do this?

[EDIT] Please note that this is for OSX not iOS. The touchesBegan method for iOS does not seem to work in OSX.

Comment: I would start with the apple documentation for sprite kit, it has a number of examples for how to manipulate touches and sprites. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here's the solution for OSX.

You must first initialize the scene (the self object) so that it monitors for clicks.

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //do this somewhere in initialization
```

In the mouseDown event handler, check to see if a node (specifically an SKSpriteNode in this case) has been touched.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    CGPoint location = [theEvent locationInNode:self]; //get location of touch
    SKSpriteNode *spriteTouched = (SKSpriteNode*)[self nodeAtPoint:location]; //get a node if touched at that location
    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE NODE
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set a name for the node . `node.name = @"node's name";`
Then in the touchesBegan method add this :

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        if([[self nodeAtPoint:location].name isEqualToString:@"node's name"]){
            //present scene code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: The touchesBegan method I have is the -(void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event, which I believe is the OSX version of - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event, which I think is the iOS version. I've seen a ton of sites that talk about the latter. There's a lot of info on how to do all this stuff for iOS, but not a lot for OS X it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its work for me

```
    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

     for (UITouch *aTouch in touches) {
         if (aTouch.tapCount >= 1) {
            // The view responds to the tap
           // do something here...
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is for iOS only, not OSX.